# How to load a plugin automatically, after opening Neovim , from Lazy.nvim plugin manager

Tags: plugins, lua, lazy-loading, neovim, neovim-plugin

[WSL-Nvim-Lazy.nvim(plugin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGt1q.png)

I have read all the documentation from https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim#-plugin-spec
I have even used Chat-gpt and https://nvchad.com/docs/config/plugins#lazy_loading

I am still new to all software developing and I need to use nvim as my main text editor as IDE, I have watched all YouTube videos and read many documentation but I am having a lot more difficulty in understanding the docs and commands.

Comment: Have you found out?

Comment: Thank you sir actually I tried doing some methods and did try something but sill there is problem occurring regarding this  method. like I can't able to load coc plugin with this in NVChad, and the code completion is not working to in it,  I haven't tried lspconfig-nvim repository till now..

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim#-plugin-spec), we can use the property `lazy`

and it also gives some example code,

```
require("lazy").setup({
  "folke/which-key.nvim",
  { "folke/neoconf.nvim", cmd = "Neoconf" },
  "folke/neodev.nvim",
})
```

So, for example, if you want to add treesitter and you want it to load after opening automatically, you could use

```
require("lazy").setup({
  "folke/which-key.nvim",
  { "folke/neoconf.nvim", cmd = "Neoconf" },
  "folke/neodev.nvim",
  { "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter", lazy = false },
})
```

When `lazy` is true, which is default, it will only load the plugin when it is needed. If `lazy` is false, it will load on startup. You can use the `priority` property to control which non-lazy plugins load first, you can read more about that on the documentation.

Comment: Great. I thought it was otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: " if you want to add treesitter and you want it to load after opening automatically, you could use" but in your example you disable lazy (lazy = false)